# добавить библиотеку через gradle с minsdk большим чем у проекта

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle

Задача. push уведомлениям Facebook нужен FCM https://developers.facebook.com/docs/push-notifications/android

последняя версия FCM(11.8.0) подключается через gradle и хочет андроид 4.0 и выше https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client

приложение имеет minSDK 11 и нам не принципиальны push-ы для юзеров с Android ниже 4.0, так что в коде мы добавим условие на проверку версии, но проблема с добавлением библиотеки. Знаю что можно доверится ManifestMerger с чем-то на подобие этого:

```
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="20" android:minSdkVersion="11"
      tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging"/>
```

Но можно ли(и как) такой же трюк провернуть в gradle?